# Unexpected header files:

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I'm getting unexpected header files with the

```
brew doctor
```

I tried `brew doctor` and then I get a huge list of files. I'm not sure if they are safe to delete or how I would delete them in the first place

```
brew doctor

Alexs-Air:~ alex$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!
```

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

```
Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform-export.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/v8-tracing.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_api_types.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/aes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1_mac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1t.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bio.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/blowfish.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/buffer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/camellia.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cast.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cmac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cms.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/comp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/crypto.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/des.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/des_old.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dh.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dso.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dtls1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/e_os2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ebcdic.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ec.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdh.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/engine.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/err.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/evp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/hmac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/idea.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/krb5_asn.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/kssl.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/lhash.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/md4.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/md5.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/mdc2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/modes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/obj_mac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/objects.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ocsp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslv.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ossl_typ.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs12.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs7.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pqueue.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rand.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc4.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ripemd.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/safestack.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/seed.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/sha.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/srp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/srtp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl23.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl3.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/stack.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/symhacks.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/tls1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ts.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/txt_db.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui_compat.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/whrlpool.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509_vfy.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509v3.h
  /usr/local/include/node/pthread-barrier.h
  /usr/local/include/node/stdint-msvc2008.h
  /usr/local/include/node/tree.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-aix.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-bsd.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-darwin.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-errno.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-linux.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-os390.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-posix.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-sunos.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-threadpool.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-unix.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-win.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-inspector-protocol.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-inspector.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-platform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-util.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-value-serializer-version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-version-string.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8config.h
  /usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/zlib.h
```

Comment: You could describe your system: CPU, OS, version numbers and alike.

Comment: I got the issue fixed. I installed Ruby On Rails. You're asking what is my CPU, OS? 1.3 GHz Intel Core i5 macOS Mojave

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm little bit late, but I had the same problem. First brew uninstall node

```
brew uninstall node
```

then I removed the Unbrewed files and then downloaded node again.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
sudo cleanup
brew install node 
brew doctor
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: please who tried this? did it work?